# Social Network app: Profile photos don't appear correctly

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I created a social network app using Java language with the ability to insert a picture as a profile photo. If I try to upload a photo of mine it works but if other users try to do it using another device they don't see my photo and I don't see theirs. Basically everyone sees their own photo using their own device.

However, despite uploading my profile photo properly, it tends to disappear after a period of time.

How to fix it?

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXo99.jpg

Code for try to setting profile photo:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                if(task.getResult().exists()){

                    String name = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String image = task.getResult().getString("image");
                    String about = task.getResult().getString("about");
                    String skills = task.getResult().getString("skills");

                    mainImageUri = Uri.parse(image);

                    setupName.setText(name);
                    setupAbout.setText(skills);
                    setupSkills.setText(about);

                    RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                    placeholderRequest = placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.defaultuser);

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest)
                            .load(image)
                            .into(setupImage);

                }

            } else {

                String error = task.getException().getMessage();

                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "C'è stato un problema, riprova per favore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setupButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    setupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String user_name = setupName.getText().toString();
            final String about = setupAbout.getText().toString();
            final String userSkills = setupSkills.getText().toString();


            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name) && mainImageUri != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (isChanged) {

                    user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    final StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("profile_images").child(user_id + ".jpg");
                    image_path.putFile(mainImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                storeFirestore(task, user_name, about, userSkills, image_path);
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "C'è stato un problema, riprova per favore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }


                        }
                    });

                } else {


                storeFirestore(null, user_name, about, userSkills, null);
            }

            } else {

             if(TextUtils.isEmpty(user_name))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Per favore, inserisci un nickname!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Per favore, inserisci una foto profilo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    setupImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SetupActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Hai autorizzato l'app ad accedere al tuo archivio esterno?", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SetupActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                } else {
                   BringImagePicker();
                }
            } else {
                BringImagePicker();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void storeFirestore(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String user_name,
                            String userSkills, String about, StorageReference image_path){

    Uri download_uri = null;
    if(task != null) {

         task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

    } else {

       download_uri = mainImageUri;

    }
    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
     userMap.put("skills", userSkills);
    userMap.put("name", user_name);
    userMap.put("about", about);
    userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());
    userMap.put("user_id", user_id);


    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Le impostazioni sono state aggiornate!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "C'è stato un problema, riprova per favore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

In the first line "user_id" is "firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();"

Code for onActivityResult:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTRJv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
Uri download_uri = null;
if(task != null) {

     task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

} else {

   download_uri = mainImageUri;

}
```

I recommend studying the documentation on [getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) (or [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)), as that really is the one and only way to get a download URL.

In your case, that'd be something like this:

```
private void storeFirestore(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String user_name,
                            String userSkills, String about, StorageReference image_path){
    image_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri download_uri) {
            Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("skills", userSkills);
            userMap.put("name", user_name);
            userMap.put("about", about);
            userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());
            userMap.put("user_id", user_id);
    
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
        
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Le impostazioni sono state aggiornate!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
        
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "C'è stato un problema, riprova per favore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
                    }
        
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });   
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my app is crashing if i try to use "  image_path.getDownloadUrl()" and logcat says me "attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference" when i try to change "  userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());" to   "userMap.put("image", image_path.toString());"... i'm really stuck here...

Comment: That's a new problem, and it sounds like you didn't initialize `image_path` in that case. You can also call `task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadURL()` in that case

Comment: Hey @Johnny1994 Any further updates here?

Comment: I have the some problem, i can't release my app for this bug...i'm going to overturn my project...thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: What's the bug? You had a mistake in how you get the download URL, which I pointed out how to fix. Did you implement the change? Does `userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());` now contain the correct value when you check it in a debugger?

Comment: Finally, after weeks of several attempts you solved my problem...or rather, it seems to be working...i deleted the second recall of storeFirestore, i used image_path.getDownloadUrl as you suggested and i called task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadURL()...i will post another screenshot...could you tell me if there is anything to improve? Very thanks Frank, for real...

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you'll need to use the `onSuccessListener` to ensure that the download URL is actually filled and ready to be used.

I see that you call the `storeFirestore` function two times, with the one on line 79 with the `image_path` parameter with null value. That's probably the cause of the crash you mentioned in the comments above.

You can try with something like this:

```
private void storeFirestore(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String user_name,
                            String userSkills, String about, StorageReference image_path){
    Uri download_uri = null;
    if (image_path != null) {
       download_uri = image_path.getDownloadUrl();
    }
    else if(task != null) {
       download_uri = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
    } else {
       download_uri = mainImageUri;
    }
    
    download_uri.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri downloaded_uri) {
            Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("skills", userSkills);
            userMap.put("name", user_name);
            userMap.put("about", about);
            userMap.put("image", downloaded_uri.toString());
            userMap.put("user_id", user_id);

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Le impostazioni sono state aggiornate!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "C'è stato un problema, riprova per favore.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i tried that but logcat says me "incompatible types: Task<Uri> cannot be converted to Uri"...if i try to migrate to Task<Uri> i have a new problem: "incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to Task<Uri>"...i don't know where is the problem...maybe in the method  onActivityResult...i will attach a new screenshot with that code...thanks anyway...